# How to lower amperage?

Tags: current, amperage

I have a power source that gives 5V DC and 700mA. I need to power a ventilator that requires 5V DC and 500mA ± 10%. What is the best way to lower the amperage, would a 10Ω resistor do the trick or should I use a transistor or something else?

Comment: You don't need to.  Supply the proper voltage and the current will be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has been answered here dozens of times. The power source has the designed capacity to deliver up to 700mA at 5V. That does not mean that it forces the load to take 700mA. Instead a load that requires 500mA at 5V will take that amount from the power source. No extra resistors or transistors needed. The only time you have to worry is if the load requires more current than the power source can provide and in that case the power source will not be able to perform. It may pop a fuse, burn up, cut out or allow the output voltage to sag to below the rated voltage.